# tRPC API calls log user out automatically

Tags: typescript, authentication, next.js, next-auth, trpc

I'm trying to build a social media application using the T3 stack (Next.js, NextAuth.js, tRPC, Prisma). I have a `protectedProcedure` route which creates a new post. However, whenever I call this route (or any other route), I get immediately logged out, and since it's a protected procedure, I get an unauthorized error.

Here's my route file (named `post.ts`):

```ts
import { z } from "zod";
import { createTRPCRouter, protectedProcedure } from "~/server/api/trpc";

export const postRouter = createTRPCRouter({
  create: protectedProcedure
    .input(z.object({ content: z.string() }))
    .mutation(async ({ input: { content }, ctx }) => {
      const post = await ctx.prisma.post.create({
        data: {
          content,
          userId: ctx.session.user.id,
        },
      });

      return post;
    }),
});
```

Here's my `[...nextauth].ts` file:

```ts
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!,
    }),
  ],
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET!,
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

And finally, here's the part in my component file that calls the API:

```ts
const createPost = api.post.create.useMutation({
  onSuccess: (newPost) => {
    setInputValue("");
  },
});

function handleSubmit(e: FormEvent) {
  e.preventDefault();
  createPost.mutate({ content: inputValue });
}
```